# Ruby on Rails: if current page? is homepage, don't show form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to not show a form, but only if current page is NOT the home page

This is what I have so far...

I have my route setup:

```
root 'projects#index'
```

My view:

```
<% if !current_page?(url_for(:controller => 'projects', :action => 'index')) %>
  show some stuff
<% end %>
```

This doesn't show if the url is `localhost:3000/projects`

But it shows if its `localhost:3000`

So I need to somehow make sure that if its the homepage, it won't show. Also, I have search parameters for the home page, and I still don't want to show if its like `localhost:3000/projects?search=blahblahblah`

Comment: If you have to check if the current page is the root page, then there is something weird going on in your partial/template structure.

Comment: @ChristianRolle `localhost:3000/projects` is my index page. root is pointing to `projects#index`, so it works for both

Comment: No. I meant something different. If you have to check in a partial or template "Is this partial rendered from root page?", then you probably created a weird partial rendering. You should not need to check if it is the root page. If you have to, then I suspect a code smell.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `root_path` helper:

```
<% unless current_page?(root_path) %>
  show some stuff
<% end %>
```

> This doesn't show if the url is `localhost:3000/projects` But it shows
>   if its `localhost:3000`

or:

```
<% unless current_page?('/') || current_page?('/projects') %>
   # '/' the same as root_path
   show some stuff
<% end %>
```

Also, according the [`documentation`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F), no need `url_for` method:

```
current_page?(controller: 'projects', action: 'index')
```

Comment: Yeah, but if I do `localhost:3000/projects` it will show. So, if there's a and/or operator for root_path and what I have, then I think that'll cover both

Comment: because `localhost:3000/projects` is not `root_path`, show full `routes.rb`, i believe you able to use `*_path` helpers for the `current_page?` helper.

Comment: `localhost:3000/projects` is to my home page, so I need to do both `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3000/projects`

Comment: add `||` (or) statements to your conditions `unless current_page?('/') || current_page?('/projects')`, also you can define only one `root` page.

Comment: `<% unless current_page?('/') || current_page?('/projects') %>` this worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `unless current_page?(root_path)` is not working for you, check your `root_path` for extra parameters, I had an extra parameter and thus it wasn't working correctly